# SSMS connect server type is grayed out

Tags: sql-server

source: SQL Server 10.50.x
destination: SQL Server 11.x (Not SQL Express. It was installed with en_sql_server_2012_standard_edition_with_service_pack_4_x64_dvd_100075944.iso)
I'm afraid I don't know much about modern MS SQL Server. I am trying to migrate from one machine to another and it looks like I need to import the maintenance plan. I found instructions that said to use SQL Server Management Studio to connect to Integration Services and export. I was able to do that from the source server, but on the intended destination server, the connect dialog box has "server type" grayed out. I installed the latest version of SSMS (18) and I was able to get the Integration Services option, but it gave an error "Class Not Registered".
Does anyone know how I can make this happen so that I can import those maintenance plans?
[image: connect button]

[image: Connect Object Explorer]

Edit: I just tried to manually create a maintenance plan and got this; so, maybe I need to start over and figure out how to install SQL Server. Something seems very wrong.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server type ist grayed out if you want to start a new connection using the "Connect" button on the left. If you klick on the "cable-symbol" (Connect Object Explorer) you can chose the server type.

> I think this is silly, no idea what the purpose is...

Regarding the "Class Not Registered" Error, I'm pretty sure your SSMS is "too new" for your Instance.
Try the oldest on this List:
[Previous SSMS releases](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6479/sql-server-management-studio-connection-to-integration-services-error-class-not-registered/)

**Edit:**

What I meant in the comment was the Management Studio, not the DB Instance. With 2012 (2008r2 maybe too) you had to install Management Tools as Feature.
I've found an old 2012 install image and started it up to show you this printscreen:
[image]
Read the Feature description and check if you have installed this feature.

Comment: Thanks, but check out the screen shots I added. That is not the case.

Comment: @Roman: Is this an Express Version of SSMS 11.0? If Yes, this might be the reason you only have the Database Engine option. Can you do a Setup Discovery Report and share the results with us?

Comment: Not SQL express. Installed with en_sql_server_2012_standard_edition_with_service_pack_4_x64_dvd_100075944.iso

Comment: @Roman: edited my answer to show you this print screen. Also I'm still positive about my statement, ssms 18 being too new to connect so 10.5/12.0 SSIS

Comment: Add to features of SSMS installation! I don't know how I missed that. Thanks. That was it.